# Visual Studio 2022 Endpoints Explorer not showing minimal apis endpoints defined in extension methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022, .net-8.0, aspnet-api-versioning

If I have the following code in my `program.cs` I get an entry in the Endpoints Explorer in Visual Studio 2023.

```
var example = app.NewVersionedApi("example");

var group = example.MapGroup("v{version:apiVersion}")
                    .HasApiVersion(1);

example.MapGet("/", () =>
{
    return Results.Ok();
});
```

If I change my code to that is comes from an extension method it does not appear.

```
public static class StaticClass
{
    public static void AddEndpoints(this IVersionedEndpointRouteBuilder example)
    {
        var group = example.MapGroup("v{version:apiVersion}")
                     .HasApiVersion(1);

        example.MapGet("/", () =>
        {
            return Results.Ok();
        });
    }
}
```

Then my `program.cs` becomes

```
var example = app.NewVersionedApi("example");
example.AddEndpoints();
```

How can I make it display in Endpoints Explorer? It does appear in Swagger.

Comment: TBH both versions does not work for me. Only explicitly calling `MapGet` on `app` works. I would suggest filing VS issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change the `IVersionedEndpointRouteBuilder` to `IEndpointRouteBuilder` and it works.
[image]